# DAX Calculate Billing Days Between Two Variable Dates

Tags: date, variables, filter, dax, measure

I have a dimdate table that is represented below.  I have each day flagged as BusinessDay Y/N.  I also have a DimSalesRep table that has a daily goal for each rep.  I want to be able to allow users to input a StartDt and EndDt with filters on the report and have a calculated column look at the business days between those dates.  I can calculate daysbetween with defined dates but I am unsure how I would use DAX with variable dates that are applied through Report filters.

I should also note I am not sure how best to handle a startdt and enddt filter based of the column, TheDate

Cheers!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reference your dimdate table twice

```
StartDate = 'dimdate'
```

```
EndDate = 'dimdate'
```

and use this measure:

```
Num BusinessDays = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('dimdate'),
    'dimdate'[BusinessDay] = "Y",
    'dimdate'[Date] >= SELECTEDVALUE(StartDate[Date]),
    'dimdate'[Date] <= SELECTEDVALUE(EndDate[Date])
)
```

[image]